# Flexbox wrap - first and last item displaying incorrectly on iPad

Tags: css, ipad, flexbox

I am having an issue with flexbox wrap on iPad. When emulating iPad in Chrome developer tools I get the result I want, all the items wrapping and displaying correctly. However, when I test using Browserstack on a physical iPad the first and last item inside the flex container do not behave the same, please see the images below for comparison.

[Dev Tools iPad Emulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPaLi.png)

[Browserstack iPad / Physcial Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Man8M.png)

I have been browsing other peoples solutions on here but to no avail. Here is the SASS snippet with solutions people have provided on other questions added, but still not working. Have also added a link to the page in question below so it can be inspected easier.

This is my Css

```css
.blogPageCards {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  .articleCard {
      flex-direction: column;
      width: calc(50% - 30px);
      margin: 0px 15px;
        &:before {
          display: none;
          content: normal;
        }
        &:after {
          display: none;
          content: normal;
        }
    }
}
```

http://nevillejohnson.dev.clicky.co.uk/inspiration/

Please let me know if you need any more information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you trying playing around fixed sizes (margin and that 30px in calcs)

Comment: Hi, not quite sure what you mean? I have a fixed size per item at 50% - 30px thanks

Comment: Margin is fixed too. I mean that a fixed size may be the cause of weird behaviours. In some devices a 15 px (or 30 or whatever) may appear great, in others at all.

Answer (score 1):

As i am unable to write comment, i am writing it here. 
I think it is not working because your browser(i assume it is IOS Safari)needs css vendor prefix to implement the flexbox.

I am unsure which IOS Safari version is your Ipad using but if it is between 3.2 - 6.1 you surely must put -webkit- before the flexbox like this

```
.blogPageCards {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;

  .articleCard {
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: calc(50% - 30px);
      margin: 0px 15px;
        &:before {
          display: none;
          content: normal;
        }
        &:after {
          display: none;
          content: normal;
        }
    }
}
```